# npm command : Cannot find module npm-cli.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Since today I can't use any npm command.

Here's what I get everytime:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Adrien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I use Windows 10. The commands for node work. I tried to uninstall Node.js, change the path in environment variables, but nothing changes...

Everything worked fine until I work on my new React.js project and got errors.

I have no npm folder in **C:\Users\Adrien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules**

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Simply just restart your PC, refresh code editor and run the command.

Comment: This worked for me as well. It started probably after a Win10 update.

Answer (score 2):

Spent the past 24 hrs trying to resolve this and good now:

Go to settings - apps - node.js.

Here, two options prevail, 'modify' or 'unistall', select 'modify' and then press the 'repair' button which appears on the next dialogue window. Doing so will re-install a complete set of the files.

Go to PwerShell (Windows) or Bash (Mac) and type in 'npm -v', you should get a positive return, i.e., a display of the npm version number successfully installed.

I needed to resolve this as a pre-requisite to installing Truffle to support my Ethereum development environment.

Comment: Not entirely sure why I needed to repair it after installing the latest version but repairing worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to wrong path of node in system variable. Please make sure that points to the right directory.

Comment: I tried paths as : C:\Users\Adrien\AppData\Roaming\npm , C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm and it's still not working. However NodeJS works.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is `npm install -D npm`. Although this is not a great solution because you need to set your workspace correctly. But, it works and you can use it on urgent basis. ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you struggle with the same probleme here how i personnaly solve it :
Just open the configuration panel windows like if you want to uninstall node, but right clic and select repair